# Login 9gag via Curl and upvote some topics

Tags: php, ajax, curl

For learning purpose and exercise from my teacher I was write a `php` code to login `9gag.com` by Curl then like some topic on this site.

**Problem 1**:

http://9gag.com/login has csrf token, so how can I retrieve that token before do login action?

**Problem 2:**

To upvote a topic we must do some ajax steps.

I have tracked this action by console window on Chrome and found that they used these link `9gag.com/vote/like`, `9gag.com/vote/unlike` or `9gag.com/vote/dislike`.

But when I use POST method to send data into above links, it's take nothing.

So am I miss something, and what is it?

Comment: maybe links wait for click event

Comment: Are you getting any error response?

Comment: i get {"id":0,"score":0,"msg":"Action not allowed."}

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, there is a hidden field in the html code:

```
<input id="jsid-login-form-csrftoken" type="hidden" value="157e2a0776d2c5a6ryf9ef69b6452ab2" name="csrftoken">
```

This guy here seems able to vote up and down with his API (https://github.com/k3min/infinigag) but the login problem still persists.. I don't think that 9gag allows to login from anywhere outside their site.

Comment: Well the whole point of the token is to allow login requests only by sources who are able to generate a valid sequence. I've even checked if there is an api which allows to login to the site but i'm afraid this isn't the case (or maybe i didn't look hard enough eheh).